# Git Push Error when uploading after commit

Tags: git, github

[image: the attached image]

some error is here...

add and remote, commit is perfect, I don't know why this error come help me...

Answer (score 2):

You local git is older than the remote ones.

You need to first `git pull` and update your local copy.
Git will ask you to merge the new commits, then you can `git push`.

If you don't like merging, you can try a `git pull --rebase`.